# HTTP request not getting complete when content-type as application/json instead of text/html

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, proxy

In my project we are using proxy to connect with multiple server api calls,

i.e, website url ---> proxy url  -----> Server ( getting result)

if I request any API call with content-type as "text/html" or undefined. It should able to get the response from the server.

For the above same request, if i change the content-type as "application/json". the request itself it not sending and it shows **pending state ** in network console (chrome console).

Since my request data type is json formate!!! Please find my request code below,

```
    $scope.login = function () {
            var request= {
                method: 'POST',
                url:  '/login',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' //undefined
                },
                data: {
                    "username"   : $scope.username,
                    "password"   : $scope.password
                }
            };
            $http(request).then(function(response) {
                //===>
            }
}
```

Can any one know, Why i'm getting this error!

Comment: Maybe your server doesn't accept 'Content-Type': 'application/json'?

Comment: @holydragon, I tried in postman tool, with content-type as "application/json". it fetches the data.

Comment: That'y curious to know, why it restring via my web server!!

Comment: Have you tried removing the headers altogether?

Comment: without header my request won't get succeed. header is mandatory.

Comment: Maybe the proxy is altering your headers?

Comment: whether it is mandatory to keep both req and res should be even/same content-type... My case req is application/json and response is text/html